# How to get server response headers in Zombie.js

Tags: zombie.js

When making a request for a page, the server sends back headers as a part of the response.

How would someone get access to the response headers from the server in Zombie.js?

Answer (score 2):

The response object is under `browser.resources`.

[Documentation on browser.resources](http://zombie.js.org/#resources)

An example

```
browser.visit('http://localhost:8080/index.html', function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(browser.resources['0'].response.headers);
    done();
});
```